Refused to load the script 'https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js' because it violates the following CSP directive
Tried running office.js I am using react js
Tried accessing sourcelocation default value after build but got the above error while doing so. Got similar issue for style sheet as well.
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/11.0.0/css/fabric.min.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.
